# Error "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements" when adding objects in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

When i try to add the object to the objectStore with .add, the console shows this error:
*DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements.* If someone can tell where this error came from it will really help me. This is the code:

```
var request = objStore.add({tarea: todo, clase: "pendiente"});

var db;

function create_to_do(){
  var todo = document.querySelector('#the-do').value;
  var transaction = db.transaction("to_do", "readwrite");
  transaction.oncomplete = function(eve){
    console.log("all done¡")
  }

  transaction.onerror= function(eve){
    console.log("something went wrong: "+ eve.target.errorCode);
  }; 

  var objStore = transaction.objectStore("to_do");
  var request = objStore.add({tarea: todo, clase: "pendiente"});
  request.onsuccess = function(eve){
    console.log("all done¡");
    console.log(eve.target.result);
  };
}

function indexDB(){
  var request = indexedDB.open('todos', 1);
    request.onsuccess = function (evt) {     
    db = this.result;
    console.log("Database Opened");
  };

  request.onerror = function (evt){
    console.log("OpenDB error: " + evt.target.errorCode);
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(evt){
    store = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore("to_do", 
              {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
    store.createIndex('clase', 'clase', {unique: false});
    console.log("index created");
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the tarea property? if I look at the example it is a variable in your case. If that is a function or something that can't be serialized in JSON, you can't save it.

Answer (score 4):

try `keyPath: 'keyPath'` or `autoIncrement: false` once you provide a "primary key" you have to set autoIncrement to false see it [here](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/search?q=autoIncrement)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to save a DOM object. Depending on what is in there, you will or won't be able to save your data. Try leaving the tarea property out of the object and save that. And let me know what is in the tarrea property

```
var todo = document.querySelector('#the-do').value;
var request = objStore.add({tarea: todo, clase: "pendiente"});
```

Comment: This is correct. Things stored in IDB must be able to be structured cloned. DOM objects don't work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm#Things_that_don't_work_with_structured_clones

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple typo. The auto-increment option to the `createObjectStore()` method must be spelled `autoIncrement` (with capital I), not `autoincrement`.

What happens is that your object store is created without a key generator, so when adding an object it's looking for an `id` property as per your key path. Because the property doesn't exist you get the `DataError`.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the time u took but is not that, i did change it and the keyPath too lol but it was not that